# Getting results from Yandex translate

Tags: reactjs, yandex

This is kind of a silly question, but I am using the Yandex API to translate words from Spanish to English, by pasing the spanish word/phrase into a function. However, I do not know how to actually return the translation from the function! How can I get my changeString method to return the res.text[0]?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Display extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button> {this.changeString(this.props.translation)} </button>
      </div>
    );
  }

  changeString = spanishText => {
    var output = null;
    var translate = require("yandex-translate")(
      "API KEY"
    );

    translate.translate(spanishText, { to: "en" }, function(err, res) {
      console.log(res.text)
    });
  };
}

export default Display;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set it in the state and update it to trigger the rerender. Like the following

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Display extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { theWord: '' };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    var output = null;
    var translate = require("yandex-translate")(
      "API KEY"
    );

    translate.translate('spanishText',{ to: "en" }, (err, res) => {
      this.setState({theWord: res});
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button> {this.state.theWord} </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Display;
```

Comment: I tried this, and it complains that it "Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined"

Comment: @Perplexityy changed that to an arrow function for automatic binding. Now that should work

Comment: Tried changing to componentDidMount = () => { but still same error!

Comment: @Perplexityy not that part. The callback of the `translate.translate` function. Check my code again I updated it

Comment: ok, but now it is no longer translating my props, it is just translating "spanishText"

Comment: @Perplexityy replace it with anything you want